# C Interpreter memory access violation while using mysql yog

Tags: loadrunner

I am using LoadRunner 11 (web protocol). I am executing with 100 users and users are coming out after 10 minutes  of execution due to C interpreter run time error memory violation exception access_violation received.

I am connecting MySQL yog database to retrieve test data for execution.

SQL yog uses only saving test data.mmdrv memory also increasing at same time.am not using anyC code in my script.my script will retrieve test data from DB, processing request and saving into DB again

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you are using no C code, then how are you connecting to the SQL yog database?

Comment: Current release is 12.6, so even if a memory issue does exist in LoadRunner you would then need to validate your issue in the current release